# functional version of setState of useState hook is not causing re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component in my webpage where user can repeat a form i.e., add a form below another form. I've achieved this by adding a plus icon besides the form. The idea is I'll store a form object which will contain all the fields' values for every form in my state. When user will add a new form I'll add a single form object after the index of the form whose add button was clicked.

Code snippet:

```
const singleFormValues = {
    email: "",
    first_name: "",
    last_name: "",
    role: Object.keys(roles)[1],
};

const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState([singleFormValues]);

const handleAddForm = (addAfterIndex) => () => {
    setFormValue(prevFormValue => {
        prevFormValue.splice(addAfterIndex, 0, singleFormValues);
        console.log({
            prevFormValue
        })
        return prevFormValue;
    });
}
```

As you can see I've created *formValue* which is an array, this will be used to render forms.
The problem is with the functional form of *setFromValue* for some reasons when I click add button handleAddForm gets executed, the *console.log* prints correct value i.e., an extra object gets added to *formValue* **but my component does not re-render.** Which leads me to believe that the state is not getting updated but it is untrue as every time I click add button, a new object is added to the state.

Can anyone point out what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem is you are are mutating the previous state and then returning the same reference. Your component will only re-render if you return a reference to a new object. In this case, you can shallow copy your previous state and mutate the shallow copy:

```
setFormValue(prevFormValue => {
  let shallowCopy = [...prevFormValue];
  shallowCopy.splice(addAfterIndex, 0, singleFormValues);
  return shallowCopy;
});
```

Secondly (and depending on how `setFormValue` is being called), you are returning a function instead of setting the state. You will likely need to remove the return:

```
const handleAddForm = addAfterIndex => {
  setFormValue(prevFormValue => {
    let shallowCopy = [...prevFormValue];
    shallowCopy.splice(addAfterIndex, 0, singleFormValues);
    return shallowCopy;
  });
};
```

Comment: I earlier thought that the argument passed to the updater function is a copy but it is not.